# Convert GD-Sharp stream to Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, image-manipulation, gd

im currently trying out GD-Sharp and wanted to convert the graphic into bitmap without saving it to image file.

GD-Sharp method to save to stream is

> bool GB.Save(Stream outStream);

for saving using stream is

```
using(FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(@"stream1.jpg")) 
{
 image.Save((System.IO.Stream)fs);
 fs.Close();
}
```

since bitmap supports stream, how do it convert GD-Sharp to Bitmap ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did something like this.

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
gdimg.Save(memStream); 
Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(memStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a MemoryStream, something like

```
gdsBitmap.Save(memStream);
memStream.Seek(0);
gdiBitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(memStream);
```